# Matplotlib not plotting all the data points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm facing a problem where I have 13 data points but Matplotlib only plot until around 8-9 data points. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np

pv = [1240, 1390, 1635, 1885, 2025, 2165, 2290, 2965, 3455, 4510, 4975, 5510, 5795]
ac = [1200, 1325, 1555, 1835, 1985, 2135, 2285, 2435, 2985]
ev = [1240, 1390, 1635, 1885, 2025, 2165, 2165, 2165, 2690]
time = np.arange(1, 14)
y1 = np.zeros(13)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot(xs=time, ys=y1, zs=pv, label="PV")
ax.plot(xs=time[0: 9], ys=(y1+1)[0: 9], zs=ac, label="AC")
ax.plot(xs=time[0: 9], ys=(y1+2)[0: 9], zs=ev, label="EV")
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticks(time)
ax.set_title("Earned Value Analysis")

ax.set_xlabel("Time(Week)")
ax.set_zlabel("Cummulative Cost")
plt.legend(loc="lower right")

plt.show()
```

Here is the output of my program:
[image: Output]

I should be getting around 5795 for PV when at time 13. However, the graph is only plotted until around time 8-9.
Thank you for anyone clearing my doubt.

Comment: Add `marker='*'` and you will see that all points are drawn. Also rotate your graph, and you will see that the highest values are above 5000.

Comment: The Axes contains the three lines and you can see from the line's data that it has 13 points... `l1,l2,l3 = ax.lines; print(l1.get_data_3d())`.